# How to perform a Neo4j database backup in Windows 10?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, database-backups

The neo4j documentation says that I gotta run some commands from the neo4j-admin tool, which is a terminal supposedly located in the bin folder, but I can't find that tool. there's also a cypher shell but when I open it as an administrator it shuts down immediately. Is there any other way of performing the backup? The neo4j version is 3.2.3.

Comment: Did you check the [file locations](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.2/configuration/file-locations/) section of the operations manual?

Comment: Have you performed a zip installation? Or have you used the Windows installer?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way to do a full database backup is coping the content of the data folder.

According the docs ([file locations](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations)):

- For /Windows zip installation the folder is `<neo4j-home>\data`
- Using desktop installer the folder is `%APPDATA%\Neo4j Community Edition`